# API Request to ManyToOne relation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to build an API which has a ManyToOne relation. It's about an Employee and Department entity. This is what I have:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Employee {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long Id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Department department;
    //SETTERS AND GETTERS, TWO CONSTRUCTORS 
}
```

Department class

```
 @Entity
@Table
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long Id;
    private String name;
    //SETTERS AND GETTERS, TWO CONSTRUCTORS 
}
```

Employee Controller

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService employeeService;

    @PostMapping("/employee")
    public Employee create (@RequestBody Employee employee){

          return employeeService.create(employee);
    }
}
```

Department Controller

```
 @RestController
 public class DepartmentController {

     @Autowired
     private DepartmentService departmentService;

     @PostMapping("/departments")
     public Department create(@RequestBody Department department) {
       return departmentService.create(department);
   }
}
```

I need to add an Department and then add and employee that belongs to that department.

This is the POST request to Department and it works.

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Depto"             
 }
```

I need to add that department to an employee

```
 {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "Employee",
     "department": 2
 }
```

This is the error that I got:

```
 .HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Cannot construct instance of 'mypackage.Department' (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (2)
```

Comment: The message is pretty clear: you're sending a JSON structure that doesn't match the structure of an employee. REST API inputs are not persistent entities. Don't use the same classes to represent different things. Use a command DTO to model your JSON input, which matches the structure of the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `department` field in the `Employee` class is an instance of `Department`, not an integer. So the JSON you're POSTing is wrong. In fact, it's bad architectural practise to use the same class for persisting in the DB as what you send over REST calls.

If you separate them (make the REST object a DTO), then you can receive the id (2), look up the department with id 2 and then put that in your new `Employee` object and save it to the database.

**Edit**: You could create an EmployeeDTO class:

```
public class EmployeeDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Long departmentId;

    ...  // getters
}
```

And your controller might have an endpoint something like this:

```
@PostMapping("/employee")
public Employee create (@RequestBody EmployeeDTO employeeDTO){

    Department department = departmentService.get(employeeDTO.getDepartmentId());

    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setId(employeeDTO.getId());
    employee.setName(employeeDTO.getName());
    employee.setDepartment(department);

    return employeeService.create(employee);
}
```

Comment: I get it, how can I do that? Jackson?

Comment: Edited to show one possible way to handle it. Obviously you'll need error handling and the like.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Is this the most optiomal solution? if I have 20 POJOs, that means I have to create 20 DTO classes as well?

Comment: It might not sound optimal, but it's part of a layered approach to software architecture. If you didn't use DTOs, what would happen if you wanted to change what you're storing in that table in the db. You'd have to update all of your REST clients as well.